# How do I prevent Cloud Firestore from splitting map key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to update a document in Firestore from a Cloud Function by adding a map, like so:

```
const data = {
        [email]: {
            somedata: somedata,
            somedata: somedata
        }
    };
docRef.update(data)
```

The problem is that Firestore is splitting the email and creating a nested map. For example, if the email is name@email.com, the value stored in Firestore is:

```
name@email
  com
    somedata: somedata
    somedata: somedata
```

I'd prefer the have that email not be split. Is this possible with Firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email address has a period (`.`) character in it.  That character is taken to be a field separator when given as a raw string as you in your example.  What Firestore is doing is assuming that you want to set a field called "name@email" with a property called "com" to the value of the object you specified.  See "Constraints on field paths" in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).

I don't believe there is a way around this.  You may want to translate that dot to some other character (maybe one that can't occur in email addresses) before accessing the database.  All your queries that use this field will have to be similarly translated.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @DougStevenson. I figured Firestore was probably making that assumption, which makes sense. Translations is a good idea. I'll give that a try.  Just to be clear, **_no_** field name in Firestore can have a dot in it? I was able to manually create the structure I wanted in the Firebase console.

Comment: I don't know of a way to programmatically update a field with a dot in it.  I believe you can set and query them, but updates seem to be special.